# UserMulti Field limit

Tags: client-object-model

Does UserMulti field have a limit on how much users are selected? I'm asking this because when I use client object model I can set at most 15 users at once.

edit: I can add more users directly on SharePoint. So the question is if there is a limit on how much users can be set on UserMulti using client object model?

edit: I discovered some funny pattern... each odd user in the list is added correctly, but each even is not...

```
var users = new List<FieldUserValue>();
//for loop in which I add users to list like this 
//users.Add(new FieldUserValue() { LookupId = someId });
item["myUserMultiField"] = users.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the users into the item, you need to delimit them with `;#`.

For example, `44;#Barack Obama;#43;#George Bush;#42;#Bill Clinton`. I think you can even get away with specifying only the IDs but you still need the delimiters.

See a [similar issue on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727684/only-alternating-values-in-spfieldmultichoice-saved/3738066#3738066).

Comment: Hmm, on the client side you can't set LookupValue on the lookup field, only LookupId... Do you think I should try without using a list of FieldUserValue and instead build a string delimted like that in your example? On the server side you have SPFieldUserValueCollection but there is not FieldUserValueCollection on the client side.

Comment: Worth a try! :) I don't have 2010 so I can't test.

Comment: How were you able to submit multiple names into your user field with object client model

Comment: @JoeL: Probably the easiest way is to build a string of the user IDs and put it in the item. For ex: `item["myUserMultiField"] = "1;#anything;#52;#anything";`. I think that is what Andrej got working.